# Flash or EEPROM

Tags: arduino, sd, eeprom, performance

EEPROM vs SD Flash

I am working on a Arduino program (a game, a slot machine) that needs to store 16 bitmaps (the slot machine symbols) that are 32 * 16 bytes each (total 8192 bytes). The bitmaps are static/immutable so does not need to be changed. The only requirement is that they need to be accessed *fast*. Thus performance prevails capacity.

Currently, I am working with an SD Card Module for Arduino by Vellman (SPI). I noticed that, opening a file, and especially seeking a byte in the filestream causes performance penalties.

So my question is: would an *EEPROM* (or 2, regarding the amount of data) be a better, or at least a faster, storage solution than a SD card given that:

- The data is only written once.
- The data is read a lot of times.
- I need to get the bytes in a nonsequential order.

**Current config:** *ATmega32U4 (Pro Micro) at 16MHz with 32 kB
program + libs needs about 30 kb.*

**Background:** App is driving 4 * ST7735 TFT displays (SPI), Clock (SPI) and 6 buttons (one pin) and currently, and SD card reader (SPI).

Comment: What prevents you from storing the data into Arduino Flash?

Comment: How much memory does your Arduino have?

Comment: ATmega32U4 (Pro Micro) at 16MHz with 32 kB
program + libs needs about 30 kb.

Comment: Um, what about not using the Arduino platform, then? That just introduces a lot of cruft you don't need. Most RTOS'es that target your MCU are much smaller, and you instantly get the space you need. Also, there's really very little reason to use an ATMega32U in 2021 – it's an expensive, slow, low-memory component.... Maybe also slimming down on third-party libraries would be an option. 30 kB on an ATMega is actually a lot.

Comment: Use a larger AVR, like ATmega480 or use a larger Arduino like "due"

Comment: Since your code is so large, have you turned code optimization on? Or made the  compiler to remove unused functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, do consider anything else than an SD card, because an SD card is totally overkill for storing 8192 bytes.

Comment: Does it add performance, is it faster?

Comment: Very likely it is faster. How fast is it now and how fast you need it to be? How fast SPI clock you have?

Comment: See my update, ATmega32U4 (Pro Micro) at 16MHz with 32 kB
program + libs needs about 30 kb.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a simple SPI or I2C SEEPROM. 8k bytes of data is very little. You can randomly access bytes.

For example, the [M95640](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/4b/e9/91/0c/24/94/4c/dc/CD00258834.pdf/files/CD00258834.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00258834.pdf) holds 8K bytes, can run at an SPI clock rate of 20MHz and costs around 30 cents.

I2C parts tend to be cheaper, whether you actually need that speed or not depends on the application.

In my experience SPI-accessed SD cards are problematic in that they have complex controllers on-board that can "go away" for a relatively long length of time compared to their (very high) throughput. Implying long worst-case latency and/or large buffers in applications that use them.

Answer (score 1):

If the values are truly constant and you want fast access, put them in an array of constants in the **program** flash memory. As you note, accessing an SD card is relatively slow.

Comment: the program flash memory is already full I am afraid...

Comment: That would have been good information to put in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I’d suggest moving to a larger capacity microcontroller, for the few cents extra it will cost it will make your storage and performance problems go away.

Never do anything at runtime that you could have done at compile time.